# Why isn't the constitutionality of Trump's 2nd impeachment decided by the supreme court?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, senate, supreme-court, impeachment

[Just five GOP senators vote Trump impeachment trial is constitutional](https://thehill.com/homenews/senate/535925-senate-rejects-paul-effort-to-declare-trump-impeachment-trial)

As I understand the US supreme court, they rule on the constitutionality of issues. Therefore it seems like the question of whether Trump's 2nd impeachment is constitutional is something they should be deciding. Why is the US Senate voting on it instead?

Comment: Before anyone gets any ideas about how this is a push question, *Just five GOP senators vote Trump impeachment trial is constitutional* is the title of the linked article, and if anyone is aware of a better source feel free to change the link in the question.

Comment: Notably the vote was over a point of order against proceeding with the trial raised by Sen. Rand Paul; the rationale for the objection was the constitutionality of the proceedings, but the practical issue at hand was process (and politics).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the Supreme Court overturn an impeachment?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39748/can-the-supreme-court-overturn-an-impeachment)

Comment: @divibisan no, and I have no idea how that question is related to this question (other than it uses the same words like "supreme court" & "impeach").

Comment: @divibisan but this question isn't about reviewing impeachments. It's about whether impeaching a former president is constitutional.

Comment: @divibisan I do not understand your question. OP asks why it is the Senate voting on the question as opposed to the Supreme Court.

Comment: @Allure Whether *convicting* a former president is constitutional.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> @divibisan but this question isn't about reviewing impeachments. It's about whether impeaching a former president is constitutional.

> @divibisan I do not understand your question. OP asks why it is the Senate voting on the question as opposed to the Supreme Court.

The supreme court never rules on the constitutionality of anything unless that question has a bearing on a case that has been brought before it.  Nobody has sued anyone on any question that turns on the constitutionality of this impeachment, so the supreme court can't rule on its constitutionality.  Furthermore, nobody is likely to sue, because it is in principle not possible to bring a suit unless the person bringing the suit has been harmed.

Furthermore, if such a question did come before the court, it's likely that it would determine that only the house and senate can make this determination, as described in Joe C's answer.

Part of the senate's sole power to try impeachments is the power to dismiss an impeachment as moot because the impeached party has left office (or for any other reason) or as unconstitutional (for any reason).  The idea that the supreme court is the only body that can decide something is unconstitutional is incorrect.  The executive can decide all by itself not to enforce a law because it believes the law to be unconstitutional, and the senate can decide all by itself that an impeachment is unconstitutional.  Similarly, if the senate finds that a bill passed by the house is unconstitutional, the senate can refrain from acting on the bill for that reason.

> If the supreme court is supposed to rule on this, how come after Rand Paul objected, the Senate didn't refer the question to the supreme court?

The supreme court does not issue advisory rulings.  The senate cannot refer the matter to the supreme court.

Comment: Indeed, the early uses of the veto was just on constitutionality until Jackson (?) started vetoing stuff he didn't like

Comment: I think the only person with standing to challenge the constitutionally of impeaching Trump after he's left office is Trump himself. He also may not be able to challenge it in court until he's actually negatively affected by it, like if a state government refuses to add his name to a presidential primary ballot because he's been disqualified after being convicted by the Senate.

Comment: Nobody is likely to sue...unless Trump is convicted and barred from holding future federal office, in which case he (or his campaign) is very likely to sue in order to gain access to ballots for the 2024 GOP primaries and/or general elections.

Comment: @RossRidge Are states even required to not put on the ballot or cast EVs for a disqualified candidate? It seems like he could still win the EC by votes; and only when the Senate doesn't certify him the winner would he have standing.

Comment: @RossRidge It's likely that he would lose his presidential pension if convicted, which would give him standing.

Comment: The Senate can decide that an impeachment is unconstitutional and choose not to pursue it, but that doesn't mean that the Supreme Court can't strike one down as unconstitutional if the Senate does decide to pursue it. If the Senate did indeed choose to convict, then I'd expect that a lawsuit would indeed be filed to overturn it as unconstitutional.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-  It would seem reasonable to me if states had measures that prevented ineligible candidates from appearing on ballots, but I don't know if that is actually the case.

Comment: I can decide not to do my laundry on Thursdays because I think it's unconstitutional...but that doesn't actually make it unconstitutional.

Comment: @reirab Well this is Trump we're talking about, of *course* he'd file a suit. He'll claim that every liberal is just a lizardman in disguise, and that the actual constitution, which is being hidden from us by radical leftist lizard-hippies, specifically states he's the Super President for all eternity, if he thinks it'll get him some attention and cheers.

Answer (score 54):

Because the US Supreme Court does not have the authority to rule on whether an impeachment is constitutional.  That power lies solely with the US Senate, as part Article I, Section 3 of the US Constitution:

> The Senate shall have the sole Power to try all Impeachments.

It is worth remembering that the President is not the only position that is subject to impeachment.  Congress has, in the past, impeached and convicted members of the judiciary for various reasons.  If the courts had the ability to rule on whether the impeachment of one of their members was constitutional, that would undermine one of the checks and balances in the constitution.

Comment: It depends on which aspect of impeachment you are talking about. The courts probably can't rule on things like what are impeachable offenses or what are the procedures of an impeachment trial, as those are not specified in the Constitution. But there are some things that are specified in the Constitution, e.g. it takes 2/3 of the Senate to convict, so if a Senate passed a rule that says it can convict on a majority and does so without a 2/3 majority, courts can probably rule that the conviction didn't happen.

Comment: In [another question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/62088/2085), it was generally agreed that someone who hasn't held federal office probably can't be impeached, as the Constitution specifies that "The President, Vice President and all civil Officers of the United States" can be impeached (though there is some debate as it's not clear if that's an exclusive list). The courts can probably rule that a conviction didn't happen if someone who hasn't held federal office were impeached and convicted. It's plausible that they can also rule on whether a former officer holder can be convicted.

Comment: The power to try an impeachment is not the same thing as the power to determine whether or not one is constitutional.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119061/discussion-on-answer-by-joe-c-why-isnt-the-constitutionality-of-trumps-2nd-imp).

Comment: @reirab True, but I'll just note that the three branches of the US government - judicial, executive, and legislative - are decidedly not equal despite all trite aphorisms to the contrary.  Only the legislative branch can raise taxes and appropriate spending.  Only the legislative branch can remove members of the other branches from office.  Neither the judicial or executive branches can remove Senators or House members from office.  IMO the US House and Senate have largely abdicated their roles in overseeing the executive and judicial branches, however.

Answer (score 15):

As I said in a comment and phoog's answer also emphasized, (in the US unlike in some European countries) there's no accepted method by which the legislative body can "pre-inquire" the (supreme) judiciary as to the constitutionality of anything the legislative does. [In fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advisory_opinion#:%7E:text=The%20United%20States%20Supreme%20Court,courts%20from%20issuing%20advisory%20opinions.)

> The United States Supreme Court has determined that the case or controversy requirement found in Article Three of the United States Constitution prohibits United States federal courts from issuing advisory opinions.

Furthermore, there's precedent *against* any individual Senator (or Representative) suing on behalf of the whole body by arguing their (voting) rights are being diminished. This was [reiterated](https://int.nyt.com/data/documenttools/gohmert-lawsuit/ae98b847bc1ff684/full.pdf) (by a lower court) recently in the lawsuit that Rep. Gohmert brought against the election of Biden:

> Because Congressman Gohmert is asserting an injury in his role as a Member of Congress rather than as an individual voter, *Raines* controls

That refers to (the SCOTUS decision in) [Raines v. Byrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raines_v._Byrd).

Thus, there's no way for Rand Paul or any Senator to pass this buck, at this stage, to SCOTUS, even if they wanted to. (If they tried somehow, it's very likely SCOTUS would decline, finding that Paul or any other Senator does not have standing.)

---

Also of some interest in this case/controversy, although the Chief of SCOTUS normally presides over presidential impeachments, John Roberts has [declined](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/01/25/politics/john-roberts-trump-impeachment/index.html) to do so for this 2nd impeachment of Trump, because under Roberts' interpretation of the relevant clause

> When the President of the United States is tried, the Chief Justice shall preside.

Since it's no longer the case that Trump is president, Roberts concluded he doesn't have to preside. But that's all (someone from) SCOTUS has decided on this matter and can decide until the case progresses through the Senate.

On the other hand, SCOTUS found/decided in [*Nixon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixon_v._United_States) (the judge, not the president) case that the Senate has very wide latitude as to what constitutes an impeachment trial. So it's not entirely clear what they might decide if this case does end up in their lap somehow (with a conviction of Trump).

But the political odds of the Senate voting to convict Trump don't look good, given the votes on that motion of Paul. One interesting bit is that the House managers (i.e. the "prosecution") is [planning](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/01/26/politics/impeachment-case-house-managers/index.html) to argue that the impeachment is constitutional. There's nothing (in theory) that prevents some Senators from changing their mind on that either, except public embarrassment etc.

> The House managers are also preparing to make the constitutional argument -- they're led by Rep. Jamie Raskin of Maryland, a former constitutional law professor -- that the Senate can convict a former President, just as it's held trials for other former officials in the past. It's a case that's taken on newfound importance in the wake of the Senate's vote Tuesday that Sen. Rand Paul forced as part of his argument that most of the Republicans think the trial is unconstitutional -- and there simply aren't 17 Republican votes needed for conviction.

Indeed, CNN argues that focusing on the constitutionality issue gives the GOP (Senators) cover from actually having to discuss the evidence against Trump:

> Senate Republicans have coalesced in recent days around the argument that the trial is not constitutional, giving them a way to push back on House Democrats' impeachment without condoning Trump's conduct when rioters attacked the Capitol on January 6, breaching the very chamber where the impeachment trial will be held.

Comment: It's Rand Paul (not Ron) and he wasn't trying to take the case before the Supreme Court, as far as I know. He raised a point of order in the Senate, which is perfectly within his powers as a Senator.

Comment: @reirab: Thank's I've corrected the typo. I know he wasn't trying to do that, but the OP is asking why there's not path to the Supreme Court straight from Senate.

Answer (score 3):

Questions of constitutionality are determined by the Supreme Court, not Congress or the President. Why, then, is the Senate voting on the question? Because Rand Paul wanted to make a point – that's all.

The Senate has no power to rule on whether the impeachment is constitutional. If it passed, Paul's motion would dismiss the case, but it would have no effect on the Constitutionality of the impeachment. What it does do is say that most Republicans don't want to have the trial and are likely going to vote for acquittal.

> “If you voted that it was unconstitutional, how in the world would you ever vote to convict somebody for this?” Paul told reporters. “This vote indicates it’s over. The trial is all over.”
>
> https://www.politico.com/news/2021/01/26/rand-paul-impeachment-462655

As for why the Supreme Court isn't ruling on this: the Supreme Court doesn't simply hand out declarations; there has to be a court case, filed by someone with standing, which gets appealed to them. Further, as addressed in [several](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/39748/19301) [other questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/61593/19301), the Supreme Court ruled in Nixon vs US that they do not have power to review impeachment: the House has **sole** power to impeach and the Senate has **sole** power to convict.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If the supreme court is supposed to rule on this, how come after Rand Paul objected, the Senate didn't refer the question to the supreme court? For that matter, why didn't Rand Paul file a case with the supreme court?

Comment: Because he's making a political point – that's the whole point! If there was a legitimate constitutional question that Paul wanted to challenge, then, yes, he should have tried to sue so that the Supreme Court could rule on it. But he didn't because there's nothing to argue – all precedent says that it's entirely up to the House and Senate to impeach and convict. Paul's motion was a motion to dismiss the trial (which is within the Senate's power) and a opening for Republicans to state publicly that they would vote to acquit.

Comment: @Allure: there's no process under the US constitution under which the Senate can do that (solicit the opinion of SCOTUS, merely advisory or otherwise) even if they wanted to. **If** Trump's impeachment proceeds and probably only if he's convicted, SCOTUS might have a say as they did in the [Nixon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixon_v._United_States) (judge not president) case. It's also entirely possible SCOTUS may just decline certiorari, i.e. not hear the case at all, in view of precedent.

Comment: @Allure this applies to many court systems in general, they can't rule on a hypothetical, but need an actual case. And no-one is arguing the earlier impeachment by the House was unconstitutional, since it happened while Mr Trump was President.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect.  The senate is perfectly capable of deciding that it a certain impeachment is unconstitutional.

Comment: Nobody questions the Senate's ability to impeach/convict.  The constitutional question is whether or not a private citizen can be impeached.  Impeachment is a tool to remove elected officials from office, but Trump is already out and returned to private life.  So why hold an impeachment trial that is sure to fail again?  I can think of a few reasons.

Comment: @phoog They can of course make their own decisions as individuals and they can certainly use that as a justification for voting to acquit or dismiss the trial. But they can’t _rule_ on the constitutionality in any real, precedent setting way.

Comment: @acpilot Technically Trump was impeached while still president. And it’s pretty clear from past precedent that leaving office does not make an impeachment moot. Senators may vote to acquit because of he’s no longer in office or because they think impeachment was a bad idea, that’s their right, but I've never heard an argument against the overall constitutionality of the impeachment

Comment: @phoog: It's not actually incorrect as stated (although perhaps slightly misleading). The Senate can declare an impeachment **un**constituional and not go through with it. There's no appeal to SCOTUS for that. (Or at least there's no case when that happened) On the other hand, SCOTUS can conceivably review an appeal for an impeachment that does go through the Senate (and convicts). Also of some note, SCOTUS declared for & by itself it has this power https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marbury_v._Madison#Criticism

Comment: @divibisan the senate can indeed rule on the constitutionality by passing a resolution expressing such a ruling.  Future senates may or may not choose abide by that ruling or by precedent, but that doesn't stop the senate from ruling if it so chooses.  And nobody else can overrule the senate, because the senate has the sole power to try impeachments.

Comment: @Fizz "SCOTUS can conceivably review an appeal for an impeachment that does go through the Senate (and convicts)": the supreme court's own precedent holds that the constitution's grant to the senate of the sole power to try impeachments excludes judicial review.  Marbury isn't about impeachment, and it is not particularly relevant.

Comment: @phoog They can do it, but what would the effect be? I'd argue that a ruling on constitutionality only has significance if it sets a precedent. Functionally, there's no difference between the Senate dismissing the charges because they say they're unconstitutional and the Senate dismissing the charges because they want to watch the Super Bowl that day. Neither would set a precedent or bind a future Senate in any way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119020/discussion-between-divibisan-and-reirab).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simple answer.  The Senate can vote on anything it wants, but that doesn't mean the vote settles the issue.  The Senate has no authority to determine any constitutional question; only the federal courts can do that with the Supreme Court as the final authority.  Rand made the motion solely for political reasons to telegraph the potential outcome of the actual trial.  He knows the Senate has no authority to determine constitutional questions.

Comment: While this is true as a general principle, in this particular case a vote on impeachment is constitutional by definition because the constitution states that they have sole power over impeachment

Comment: It's true that the Supreme Court is the ultimate authority on constitutional questions, but that does not mean that the Senate doesn't have authority to decide constitutional questions regarding its work that courts have not yet ruled on. Raising a point of order (as Senator Paul did) is exactly what members of Congress are supposed to do when they believe a matter before their house of Congress violates the Constitution, U.S. law, or congressional rules.

Comment: @KevinWells Yes, but the *question* about whether or not they have that power is the jurisdiction of the Supreme Court. There is no exception for impeachment. There seems to be a huge misunderstanding on this point in the highest voted answer.

Comment: @JBentley Technically yes they could rule on whether or not the Senate has this power, but it would be perhaps the most trivial ruling in history since the Constitution literally says "The House of Representatives shall chuse[sic] their Speaker and other Officers; and shall have the sole Power of Impeachment" and later says of the Senate "The Senate shall have the sole Power to try all Impeachments." That is about as clear as it could possibly be, and any interpretation that denied them that power would be insane

Comment: @KevinWells Yes, but let's be realistic here. Nobody is disputing the lines you have quoted. The part which is up for dispute is in Article II, Section 4: *"The **President**, Vice President and all civil Officers of the United States, shall be removed from Office on Impeachment for, and Conviction of, Treason, Bribery, or other high Crimes and Misdemeanors."*. There very much *is* a non-trivial question as to whether the Senate has the power to try an ex-President, and it is something the Supreme Court can rule on.

Comment: @KevinWells Or to make the point more generally, it should be clear that the Senate doesn't have the power of impeachment over every citizen on earth. There *are* limits, notwithstanding the phrase *"The Senate shall have the sole Power to try all Impeachments"*. The simple way of looking at it is to realise that the word "Impeachment" in that sentence has a specific meaning and it has to actually *be* a [valid] impeachment for the Senate's power to be effective. Whether something *is* an impeachment can be disputed.

Comment: @JBentley If the question is whether or not you can impeach an ex-president then that doesn't apply here. He was impeached while he was still president, and now the trial is being held after he left office. If the question is whether or not the issue is now moot since he has already left office then perhaps there is a reasonable question to be answered there, but conviction on impeachment charges can not just remove an officer, but can prevent them from ever holding office again, so there is a valid purpose to continuing a trial

Comment: @KevinWells yes, but we’re not talking about impeaching an ex-president. We are talking about *sentencing* an ex-president. That is to say, can any action be taken against him now that he is not the sitting president. Do they *have* the legal right to even vote to sentence him? It is a reasonable question to ask and address, though most likely the answer is “yes it is legal”.

Comment: @KevinWells We're not debating whether or not the Senate can impeach or try an ex-president, or whether there is a valid purpose to continuing a trial. We're debating whether or not that these are matters for the Supreme Court to determine.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple answer that has so far been overlooked, which is that there really isn't any serious question about the Constitutionality of Trump's impeachment and trial.  What you are seeing is a bunch of Republican Senators frantically trying to find some halfway plausible excuse not to hold a trial.

They are caught in a serious political bind.  A majortity of Americans want to see Trump tried and convicted.  (Per recent polls, e.g. https://www.politico.com/news/2021/01/25/majority-supports-trump-impeachment-462264 )  However, a majority of Republicans don't.

So if the trial is held and they vote to convict, they will likely face serious primary opposition from Trump supporters in the next election.  But if they vote to acquit, they will win the primary but are very likely to lose in the general election.

Thus claiming that a trial can't be held is an obvious, and somewhat defensible, way of trying to weasel out of their bind.

Comment: "Somewhat defensible" is pretty generous don't you think?

Comment: The point about the political bind - and the political advantages of deeming the trial unconstitutional - is certainly a very valid one, but the first sentence is not correct. There is indeed a legal question over whether someone who is no longer a government official can be tried in an impeachment. Personally, I'd like to see Trump banned from being able to run for office again, but my desire to see it happen doesn't mean it's legal. If you do indeed have an example of precedent that this is legal, then please cite it. Otherwise, don't claim it isn't an open question of law.

Comment: @reirab: It's not an open question, because it was done.  In 1876, Secretary of War William Belknap was about to be impeached by the House.  He resigned, the House impeached him anyway, and the Senate tried (and acquitted) him.  So no serious question that it can be done, because it HAS been done.

Comment: @jamesqf If he was acquitted, then there was presumably no cause for the constitutionality of the trial to have been reviewed by a court. So, no, that does not mean that it is not an open question. Indeed, the reason for his acquittal was apparently precisely that an insufficient number of Senators to convict him believed that the Senate had jurisdiction as a result of his resignation prior to the trial.

Comment: @reirab: Accepting that for the sake of discussion, that would still mean that it's legally pointless for Senators to argue that the trial is unconstitutional, unless & until Trump is eventually convicted.  Which doesn't get them out of their current bind re having to vote one way or the other in the trial.

Comment: @jamesqf Just to clarify your first comment, are you saying a *court held* that that trial was valid? Because (generally, not just in this instance) the fact that something happened says nothing about whether it was legal or not, nor does it set a legal precedent.

Comment: @JBentley: No.  My point is that the Senators concerned don't really care one way or the other about unconstitutionality, they just want to weasel out of their bind.  As for the court issue, while of course I'm not a lawyer, I would think that it CAN'T be tested in court, because the Constitution explicitly says that "The Senate shall have the sole Power to try all Impeachments.", so the Supreme Court would refuse to hear any case.

Comment: @jamesqf That is a misunderstanding which has come up a few times on this post. The Supreme Court *can* hear such a case. Just because the Senate has the sole power to try all impeachments, doesn't mean they can do whatever they like. For example, can they impeach my pet cat in London? The point to realise is that in order for the Senate to have the power to try an impeachment, the thing being considered has to actually *be* a valid impeachment. In the present case the argument would be that an ex-president is not impeachable therefore there is no impeachment at all.

Comment: @jamesqf Such an argument would be made based on section 4 of article II which says: "The President, Vice President and all civil Officers of the United States, shall be removed from Office on Impeachment for, and Conviction of, Treason, Bribery, or other high Crimes and Misdemeanors." Note how it doesn't allow for impeachment of anyone who isn't a president, VP, or civil officer, so if the Senate attempted to try someone not on that list, there would be a question which the Supreme Court would have jurisdiction over.

Comment: @JBentley: Trump wasn't an ex President when impeached.  The argument that, having been impeached while in office, he can't be TRIED after leaving office argues that impeachable officers can do anything they please in the last days of their terms, as long as the clock runs out before the Senate can try them.  But to repeat yet again, my point is that this is really irrelevant.  The constitutionally argument is just Republican Senators trying to avoid having to cast a vote which will be hugely unpopular with a large number of voters.

Comment: @jamesqf And those would be arguments that the opposing side can potentially argue.... at the Supreme Court. Note that I'm not saying that you're right or wrong, I'm merely saying that the Supreme Court *does* have jurisdiction to decide it. The fact that there seems to be a reasonable argument on one side doesn't change that. One can equally argue (and it probably will be argued in the unlikely event that Trump is convicted) that "shall be removed from Office [on...] Convction" implies that it is meaningless to apply the process to someone not in office.

Comment: @JBentley: I guess we'll have to disagree, since the only way to definitively settle the question is for someone to bring a case to the SC and see if they'll accept it.  But I'd note the other consequence of a conviction: that the person can then be barred from holding any Federal office, which is most relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

## If the senate wants to hold an impeachment trial, then the senate can hold an impeachment trial - end of story.

It would violate the principle of separation of powers for the supreme court to forbid the senate from holding certain proceedings. There's really no question - it's up to the senate to hold a trial or not.

Where the supreme court could potentially step in is after the fact. It might rule on the legal effect of whatever the senate did. However, a suit would need to be filed first and injury must be alleged. It's not clear to me what basis such a suit would have. Most likely such a suit would go nowhere because the point is moot.

However, *if* the senate votes to convict by a 2/3 majority and *if* congress also votes to forbid Trump from holding federal office again and *if* Trump runs for such an office anyway and *if* Trump wins that election, then there would be a reason for the supreme court to rule on the matter. But there are a lot of ifs there.

Comment: I think you have too many ifs there. After the first two ifs, there would be a reason because Trump would be forbidden from actually running for office. There's a pretty solid reason even after the first if given the huge reputational harm for the first ever convicted president.

Comment: The text of the constitution doesn't forbid running for office, just holding it. It would be up to states to determine whether Trump can be on the ballot.

Comment: True, but in practice the effect is the same (i.e. there is no point running for an office you can't hold), so there would still be a cause of action.